# Keyerror message

Tags: python, keyerror

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\khalha\\Desktop\\RealExcel')
filename = 'sales.csv'

Sales = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')
iFlow = Sales.loc[Sales['Product'].str.contains('iFlow', na=False)]["Status"]
print(iFlow)
```

I am getting the error:

```
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Status'
```

I do not know why I am getting this because I have used the same code for another excel spreadsheet and it works fine.

Comment: Seems there's a problem with the subset of your `Sales` `DataFrame`, could you `print` a few rows to see how it looks? Is `'Status'` in the columns?

Comment: @TomasFarias  Yes, I printed Sales and all the columns do appear.

Comment: Mind sharing a snippet of your `Sales` `DataFrame`, or some dummy data? Also, I would use `Sales.loc[Sales['Product'].str.contains('iFlow', na=False), "Status"]` to avoid [chained assigment problems](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

Comment: @TomasFarias Okay I posted the picture as an answer, Let me know if you need to see more, also one of the name of the products is Iflow, but I cant show that far down the list.

Comment: @TomasFarias I figured it out, it seemed to be some sort of spacing problem. Thank you for your help